# Assigning a value to an instance of a model outside of Model::create in a controller

Tags: php, laravel, crud

I am using laravel to make a website. In this website I have made a file upload system which works inside of the create function in the controller. In this function I am saving the image and at the same time assigning the `fileName` to the model. However, this value disappears after the redirect. I have die dumped it right before the redirect and there it is assigned.

My question is why is the `fileName` disappearing?

My create function that makes an instance of my model:

---

Edit: the beers.store should be beers.index

```php
public function store(Request $request) {
    $b = Beer::create($request->validate([
        'name' => ['required', 'min:3', 'max:20'],
        'nameOfFile',
        'brewery' => ['required', 'min:5', 'max:25'],
        'ABV' => ['required']
    ]));

    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $name = $requiest->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $b->nameOfFile = $name;
        $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/images', $b->id . ' ' . $name);
    }

    return redirect(route('beers.store', ['beer' => $b]));
}
```

Comment: disappearing means its not available in redirected route or in database table not inserted ?

Comment: Please, share your code not an image as the image can be deleted and the post lose its meaning...

Comment: Beers.store is what? please include the route you are redirecting too.

Comment: @mrhn
I have a `Route::resource('/beers', BeerController::class);` and in my BeerController one of the CRUD functions is my store method. This is where I the problem arises.

Comment: But store is an post method, you can redirect to post?`

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be that I was not calling `$b->save();`
Another way I could have fixed the problem is by doing `Beer::find($b->id)->update(['nameOfFile' => $name]);` but this adds unnecessary queries to the code, making it less optimized.